# Flash: Listen to all events of a type with one eventlistener

Tags: actionscript-3, events

It's not a matter of life or death but I wonder if this could be possible:

I got a couple of events from one type of custom event (FormEvent) now I got a FormListener that listens to all those events and handles them according to the event type. Instead of adding one eventListener at the time I wish to add all events at once.

so now it looks like this:

```
        private function addListeners():void {

        addEventListener(FormEvent.SHOW_FORM, formListener);
        addEventListener(FormEvent.SEND_FORM, formListener);
        addEventListener(FormEvent.CANCEL_FORM, formListener);
    }



        private function formListener(event:formEvent):void {

        switch(event.type){
            case "show.form": 
                // handle show form stuff
            break;
            case "send.form":
                // handle send form stuff
            break;
            case "cancel.form":
                // handle cancel form stuff
            break;
        }
    }
```

but instead of adding every event one at the time I would rather be doing something like

```
    private function addListeners():void {

        addEventListener(FormEvent.*, formListener);
    }
```

I wonder if something like this is possible, i would love it. I work with loads of events :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only really need one event listener in this case anyhow.  That listener will be listening for any change with the form and a parameter equal to what the change was becomes available to the event listener function. I will show you, but please remember that this is a pseudo situation and normally I wouldn't dispatch an event off of something as simple as a method call because the dispatch is implied so there is no real need to listen for it.

First the Custom Event

```
package com.yourDomain.events
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    public class FormEvent extends Event
    {
        //Public Properties
        public static const CANCEL_FORM:int = "0";
        public static const SHOW_FORM:int = "1";
        public static const SEND_FORM:int = "2";

        public static const STATE_CHANGED:String = "stateChanged";

        //Private Properties
        private var formState:int;

        public function FormEvent(formState:int):void
        {
            super(STATE_CHANGED);
            formState = formState;
        }
    }
}
```

So we have just created our custom event class and we have set it up so that we can catch the state through the listener function as I will demonstrate once done with the pseudo form class that will dispatch the for said custom event.

Remember that this is all hypothetical as I have no idea what your code looks like or how your implementing things.  What is important is to notice that when I dispatch the event I need to send a parameter with it that reflects what the new state is.

```
package com.yourDomain.ui
{
   import flash.events.Event;
   import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
   import com.yourDomain.events.FormEvent;
   public class Form extends EventDispatcher
   {
     public function Form():void
     {
        //Anything you want form to do upon instantiation goes here.
     }
     public function cancelForm():void
     {
        dispatchEvent(new Event(FormEvent.CANCEL_FORM);
     }
     public function showForm():void
     {
        dispatchEvent(new Event(FormEvent.SHOW_FORM);
     }
     public function sendForm():void
     {
        dispatchEvent(new Event(FormEvent.SEND_FORM);
     }
   }
}
```

And finally we create the document class that will listen for it.  Please know that I realize it isn't logical to create a listener that fires when you call a method of a class because you obviously know you called the method, but for this example it will due.

```
package com.yourDomain.ui
{
   import com.yourDomain.ui.Form;
   import com.yourDomain.events.FormEvent;
   //Form is in the same package so we need not import it.
   public class MainDocumentClass
   {
      private var _theForm:Form;

      public function MainDocumentClass():void
      {
         _theForm  = new Form();
         _theForm.addEventListener(FormEvent.STATE_CHANGED, onFormStateChange, false, 0, true);
         /*
         The following three method calls each cause the
         FormEvent.STATE_CHANGE event to be dispatched.  
         onFormStateChange is notified and checks what 
         the last change actually was.
         */
         _theForm.cancelForm();
         _theForm.showForm();
         _theForm.sendForm();
      }
      private function onFormStateChange(e:FormEvent):void
      {
         switch(e.formState)
         {
            case CANCEL_FORM:
              trace('The form was canceled');
              break;
            case SHOW_FORM:
              trace('The form was revealed');
              break;
            case SEND_FORM:
              trace('The form was sent');
              break;
         }
      }
   }      
}
```

I hope that this was helpful, its late and I may have to revise some things later, but this should help get an understanding of how to make your own events and to customize how things work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any routines that let you do that directly, but you could write your own.  The syntax here won't be perfect, but here's a first pass:

```
private function addMultipleEventListeners( evts:Array, callback:function ):void
{
    for each( var evt:Event in evts )
    {
        addEventListener( evt, callback );
    }
}
```

You could then call that routine like so:

```
var evts:Array = [ FormEvent.SHOW_FORM, FormEvent.SEND_FORM, FormEvent.CANCEL_FORM ];
addMultipleEventListeners( evts, formListener );
```